# How to display static swagger yaml file at application url /swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I created yaml file (openapi 3.0.0 format) as a documentation for our API. I would like to display this (static) swagger-ui yaml file at URL, where the application is running. Something like http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui . Where is displayed graphical representation of yaml file (same as [here](https://petstore.swagger.io/) ). Yaml file is placed in root folder in project.

I am running application on java 11, springboot 2.1.5, building with maven.

I tried generate swagger yaml from code using

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But this one is not perfect (missing default values, descriptions..)

I tried [spring static resources](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) with no success. The problem is that yaml file is not html.

Is there another (maybe better) way, how to display api documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to finish this task using @Configugarion class

```java
@Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

      private final String swaggerUILocation = "whatEverLocationYouWant";
      private final String swaggerApiDocsLocation = "whatEverLocationYouWant";

      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(swaggerUILocation + "**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/swagger-ui/");
        registry.addResourceHandler(swaggerApiDocsLocation + "**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/swagger/");
      }
    }
```

Then we used swagger-ui jar file, unziped it into resources folder and replace one row in file index.html here:

```
<script>
      window.onload = function () {
        // Begin Swagger UI call region
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: "placeHereExactLinkToYourYamlFile",
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          deepLinking: true,
          presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
          ],
          plugins: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
          ],
          layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        })
        // End Swagger UI call region

        window.ui = ui
      }
    </script>
```

The swagger html is visible and is working next to an application.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add swagger UI dependency too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then you can access swagger ui using,

```
http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui.html#/
```

try add this to your method,

```
public void yourMethod(@ApiParam(name = "id", required = true, value = "The id of the site", defaultValue = "3F7B07E2") String id)
```

Comment: I already did, sorry, that I dont write it. But the problem with generated documentation is with missing default values and descriptions (which has to be done manually or I am wrong?). So I already created this yaml file but I dont know how to display it in html next to an application.

Comment: I've edited my answer. try adding @ApiParam annotation to your method

Comment: Thank you for the information, but we are using objects generated from xsd files. And those generated files could not be edited at all. I will describe our solution in answer.